# Persisting an entity via a logged in user in spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a team entity that has one to many relationship with a player entity, the player entity has a one to one relationship with the userlogin entity which implements spring security features to handle logins, my question is:

Is it possible to persist a player to a selected team by finding out the current user who is logged in and querying the player repository for that user, and finally adding that player that matches the logged in user to team?

My logic is as follows in the controller:
 Creating a new userlogin object, finding out the current logged in user object and parsing that to type userlogin, then im getting that users id and checking the players repository for this users id then finally adding this player to the team and persisting it.

Is this the right way to go about this or are my entities relationships not correct?

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {


      @Autowired
        UserLoginRepository userRepository;

      @Autowired
            TeamRepository teamRepository;

      @Autowired
        GameRepository gameRepository;

      @Autowired
            LeagueRepository leagueRepository;

      @Autowired
            PlayerRepository playerRepository;

     @Autowired
        ManagerRepository managerRepository;

     @Autowired
        PhysioRepository physioRepository;

     @Autowired
        CoachingStaffRepository coachingStaffRepository;

   @RequestMapping(value="/jointeam", method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public String joinTeam(@Valid Team team, Principal principal)
   {

       UserLogin user1 = new UserLogin();
       user1 = (UserLogin) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

       Long id = user1.getId();



       Player player = new Player();


       player = playerRepository.findByLoginId(id);

       team.addPlayer(player);

       teamRepository.save(team);


               return "parseGame";
   }
```

Here is the error im getting when running this code:

```
2018-01-17 14:05:05.312 ERROR 11460 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to com.FYP.Club.model.UserLogin] with root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to com.FYP.Club.model.UserLogin
    at com.FYP.Club.controller.HomeController.joinTeam(HomeController.java:116) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
```

Heres my player repository:

```
@Repository
public interface PlayerRepository extends JpaRepository<Player, Long> {

//  Player findByUserLogin(UserLogin user);

//  Player findByUserLogin(Long id);

    Player findByLoginId(Long id);

}
```

My team entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "team")

public class Team implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String teamName;
    private int leaguePosition;
    public String teamAddress;
    public String level;

    @OneToOne
    private Manager manager;

    @OneToOne
    private Physio physio;


    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     public Set<CoachingStaff> coachingStaff;


    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     public Set<Player> players;

    public Team() {

    }

    public Team(Long id, String teamName, int leaguePosition) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.teamName = teamName;
        this.leaguePosition = leaguePosition;
    }



    public Team(Long id, String teamName, int leaguePosition, Manager manager) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.teamName = teamName;
        this.leaguePosition = leaguePosition;
        this.manager = manager;
    }



    public Team(Long id, String teamName, int leaguePosition, Manager manager,
            Physio physio) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.teamName = teamName;
        this.leaguePosition = leaguePosition;
        this.manager = manager;
        this.physio = physio;
    }



    public Team(Long id, String teamName, int leaguePosition,
            String teamAddress, String level, Manager manager, Physio physio,
            Set<CoachingStaff> coachingStaff, Set<Player> players) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.teamName = teamName;
        this.leaguePosition = leaguePosition;
        this.teamAddress = teamAddress;
        this.level = level;
        this.manager = manager;
        this.physio = physio;
        this.coachingStaff = coachingStaff;
        this.players = players;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public int getLeaguePosition() {
        return leaguePosition;
    }

    public void setLeaguePosition(int leaguePosition) {
        this.leaguePosition = leaguePosition;
    }

    public Set<Player> getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }

    public void setPlayers(Set<Player> players) {
        this.players = players;
    }

    public Set<CoachingStaff> getCoachingStaff() {
        return coachingStaff;
    }

    public void setCoachingStaff(Set<CoachingStaff> coachingStaff) {
        this.coachingStaff = coachingStaff;
    }

    public Manager getManager() {
        return manager;
    }

    public void setManager(Manager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    public Physio getPhysio() {
        return physio;
    }

    public void setPhysio(Physio physio) {
        this.physio = physio;
    }

    public String getTeamAddress() {
        return teamAddress;
    }

    public void setTeamAddress(String teamAddress) {
        this.teamAddress = teamAddress;
    }

    public String getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setLevel(String level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public void addPlayer(Player player){
        players.add(player);
    }

}
```

My player entity:

```
@Entity
public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String position;
    private Date dob;
    private Boolean injured;
    private String previousInjuries;


    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     public Set<PlayerSeasonStat> playerStats;

    @OneToOne
       private UserLogin login;

    public Player()
    {

    }

    public Player(String position, Date dob,
            Boolean injured, String previousInjuries) {
        super();

        this.position = position;

        this.dob = dob;

        this.injured = injured;
        this.previousInjuries = previousInjuries;
    }



    public Player(int id, String position, Date dob, Boolean injured,
            String previousInjuries, Set<PlayerSeasonStat> playerStats,
            UserLogin login) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.position = position;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.injured = injured;
        this.previousInjuries = previousInjuries;
        this.playerStats = playerStats;
        this.login = login;
    }



    public UserLogin getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(UserLogin login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }



    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }


    public Boolean getInjured() {
        return injured;
    }

    public void setInjured(Boolean injured) {
        this.injured = injured;
    }

    public String getPreviousInjuries() {
        return previousInjuries;
    }

    public void setPreviousInjuries(String previousInjuries) {
        this.previousInjuries = previousInjuries;
    }

    public Set<PlayerSeasonStat> getPlayerStats() {
        return playerStats;
    }

    public void setPlayerStats(Set<PlayerSeasonStat> playerStats) {
        this.playerStats = playerStats;
    }
```

My user login entity:

```
@Entity
public class UserLogin {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Long phone;
    private String email;
    private String address;
    private String password;
    private boolean userStatus;
    private String userType;




    public UserLogin()
    {

    }



    public UserLogin(Long id, String firstName, String lastName, Long phone,
            String email, String address, String password, boolean userStatus,
            String userType) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
        this.address = address;
        this.password = password;
        this.userStatus = userStatus;
        this.userType = userType;
    }





    public String getUserType() {
        return userType;
    }



    public void setUserType(String userType) {
        this.userType = userType;
    }



    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Long getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(Long phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean getUserStatus() {
        return userStatus;
    }

    public void setUserStatus(boolean userStatus) {
        this.userStatus = userStatus;
    }
}
```

And finally the html page that invokes the methods above. Note I am using Thymeleaf:

```
 th:each="team : ${teams}"
 th:text="${team.teamName}"
 th:text="${team.teamAddress}"
 th:text="${team.level}"
     th:text="${team.manager}"></td>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">View Team</button>  

         th:action="@{/jointeam}" method="post" th:object="${team}"

        <button onclick="myFunction()">Join Team</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the ClassCastException:

```
// user1 = (UserLogin) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
String userName = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal().getUsername();
```

Then look up the user's id:

```
 // assuming method exists in the repo
 long id = userRepository.findByUserName(userName).getId();
// use id to persist in other repos...
```

Also, doing something like this:

```
Player player = new Player();
player = playerRepository.findByLoginId(id);
```

is pointless.  `player` is assigned a new instance, but then it's immediately reassigned to some other instance (or null) so the original player is no longer referenced and will need to be garbage collected.  Just do this:

```
Player player = playerRepository.findByLoginId(id);
```

Comment: @Andrew S, thanks for explaining this to me, I have implemented the code you suggested but im still getting an exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to java.security.Principal
on:
    String userName = (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getName();

Comment: That's because you've got no property on UserLogin called userName.....use the base repository method findOne(id) to find your entity by its primary key.

Comment: Looks like you've edited your comment - in this case it looks like your source code is out of line with your compiled code....